# bitrix компонент поиска

Tags: битрикс, поиск

Как настроить поиск что бы он искал ТОЛЬКО товары?
Сейчас он выдает товары и разделы, и то и другое является элементом массива результата, что в следствии растягивает пагинацию а также на каждой страничке выводятся определенное число элементов, среди которых и разделы. Тоесть просто скрыть их не получится, надо осуществить поиск только по товарам.

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:search.page",
    "search.main",
    Array(
    "RESTART" => "N",   // Искать без учета морфологии (при отсутствии результата поиска)
        "CHECK_DATES" => "N",   // Искать только в активных по дате документах
        "USE_TITLE_RANK" => "N",    // При ранжировании результата учитывать заголовки
        "DEFAULT_SORT" => "rank",   // Сортировка по умолчанию
        "arrFILTER" => array(   // Ограничение области поиска
            0 => "iblock_catalog",
        ),
//      "arrFILTER_main" => "",
//      "arrFILTER_iblock_services" => array(
//          0 => "all",
//      ),
//      "arrFILTER_iblock_news" => array(
//          0 => "all",
//      ),
        "arrFILTER_iblock_catalog" => array(    // Искать в информационных блоках типа "iblock_catalog"
            0 => "all",
        ),
        "SHOW_WHERE" => "N",    // Показывать выпадающий список "Где искать"
        "SHOW_WHEN" => "N", // Показывать фильтр по датам
        "PAGE_RESULT_COUNT" => "24",    // Количество результатов на странице
        "AJAX_MODE" => "N", // Включить режим AJAX
        "AJAX_OPTION_SHADOW" => "Y",
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",  // Включить прокрутку к началу компонента
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y", // Включить подгрузку стилей
        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",   // Включить эмуляцию навигации браузера
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",    // Тип кеширования
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000", // Время кеширования (сек.)
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N", // Выводить над результатами
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",  // Выводить под результатами
        "PAGER_TITLE" => "Результаты поиска",   // Название результатов поиска
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N", // Выводить всегда
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "lenal",    // Название шаблона
        "USE_SUGGEST" => "N",   // Показывать подсказку с поисковыми фразами
        "SHOW_ITEM_TAGS" => "N",    // Показывать теги документа
        "SHOW_ITEM_DATE_CHANGE" => "N", // Показывать дату изменения документа
        "SHOW_ORDER_BY" => "N", // Показывать сортировку
        "SHOW_TAGS_CLOUD" => "N",   // Показывать облако тегов
        "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "", // Дополнительный идентификатор
        "NO_WORD_LOGIC" => "N", // Отключить обработку слов как логических операторов
        "FILTER_NAME" => "",    // Дополнительный фильтр
        "arrFILTER_iblock_visible_goods" => array(
            0 => "all",
        ),
        "USE_LANGUAGE_GUESS" => "Y",    // Включить автоопределение раскладки клавиатуры
        "SHOW_RATING" => "",
        "RATING_TYPE" => "like_graphic",
        "PATH_TO_USER_PROFILE" => "",
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "clear"
    ),
    false
);?>
```

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд самый простой вариант:

1) Добавить обработчик [BeforeIndex](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/search/events/beforeindex.php), в котором добавить дополнительные параметры для товаров. То есть проверяем, что индексируемый элемент является товаром и добавляем свой параметр, например:

```
$arFields["PARAMS"]["is_product"] = 'Y';
```

2) Добавить фильтр по этому параметру для компонента поиска. Получится примерно так:

```
global $arSearchFilter;
$arSearchFilter = [
    'PARAMS' => [
        'is_product' => 'Y'
    ]
];
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
     "bitrix:search.page",
     "searchpage",
     array(
        "FILTER_NAME" => "arSearchFilter",
        //// тут остальные параметры
     ),
     false
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут либо переработка компонента, либо в шаблоне bitrix:search.page нужно производить фильтрацию уже полученных результатов.

Что-то по типу такого

```
$filterElements = [];

$getElements = CIBlockElement::GetList(
        [],
        [
            'IBLOCK_ID' => 52,
            '=ID' => $arElements
        ],
        false,
        false,
        [
            'ID'
        ]
);

while ($elm = $getElements->fetch())
{
    $filterElements[] = $elm;
}
```

И фильтр уже подсовывать в компонент для вывода элементов.

Костыль тот еще, канешн. Ну а что поделать с этим битриксом.

Либо второй вариант сделать свой компонент на основании текущего и исправить выборку в нем. Так будет правильнее